# Using random.choice to print two words from a random line in a file

Tags: python

I'm currently making a music quiz game and I'm trying to select a random line and print the 2 variables I've already assigned in that line, however I can't find a good way to do this. Bellow you can see what I've done so far along with how linked 2 variables per line in the file. Thanks for any help!

## This is how I'm adding variables to the different lines

```
    Artist='Cold Play';Song1='Clocks'
    file.write(Artist + " " + Song1 + "\n")


    Artist='Beatles';Song1='Revolution'
    file.write(Artist + " " + Song1 + "\n")


    Artist='Pharrel Williams';Song1='Happy'
    file.write(Artist + " " + Song1 + "\n")


    Artist='Owl City';Song1='Fireflies'
    file.write(Artist + " " + Song1 + "\n")


    Artist='Oasis';Song1='Wonderwall'
    file.write(Artist + " " + Song1 + "\n")

    file.close()
```

## This Is the bit I'm stuck with

```
    Song = (random.choice(open("SongFile2.txt").read().split()))



    print("Please type yes to continue playing")
    print("or type something random to recieve a nice message and quit the 
    game")

    PlayerAnswer = input()

    if PlayerAnswer == ("yes"):


       print("Question:" + str(Question))

       print("" + Song1[0] + ": This is the first letter of the song" )
       print("The Artist is: " + Artist)


       print("Now guess the Song (Remember to use capital letters for 
       Names)")

       PlayerGuess = input()
```

What I want is for the program to output the first letter of a song and the Artist associated with the song from a random line of the file

Comment: You have lines like `Cold Play Clocks` in your file. How can you determine if it's not `Cold` and `Play Clocks`?

Comment: You representation in the file is bad: how do you - only using the created file - distinguish between artists that have a 2 names and 1 name titles (`Pharrel Williams Happy`) and those that have 1 name and 2 word titles (`Coldplay The Scientist`) ?

Comment: Also: do not use ; in pyhton code - read https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ for more infos

Comment: Also: this `Song = (random.choice(open("SongFile2.txt").read().split()))` does not respect song titles or artists at all - it might give you an artist name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should switch the way to store your data - use a seperator character between artist and song that does not occur in either one.

A `'|'` is a good divider for songs and artists. You can use it like so:

Write data file:

```
# use a seperator character between artist and song that does not occur in either
with open("songs.txt","w") as f:
    f.write('''Cold Play|Clocks
Beatles|Revolution
Pharrel Williams|Happy
Owl City|Fireflies
Oasis|Wonderwall''')   # write a multiline-file
```

Game:

```
import random

def get_all_music():
    """Load music from songs.txt and return as list of 2-elem-lists.
    Lines not containing | are ignored."""
    with open("songs.txt") as f:
        return [x.strip().split("|") for x in f.readlines() if '|' in x]

all_music = get_all_music()

for _ in range(3):
    artist, song = random.choice(all_music)
    print("Song starting with '{}' by '{}'.".format(song[0],artist))
    s = input("What is it's name?")
    if s == song:
        print("Correct!")
    else:
        print("'{}' is wrong. It was '{}'".format(s,song))
```

Output:

```
Song starting with 'C' by 'Cold Play'.
What is it's name? Clocks
Correct!
Song starting with 'F' by 'Owl City'.
What is it's name? Clocks
'Clocks' is wrong. It was 'Fireflies'
....
```

Answer (score 0):

The `read()` method returns the entire file contents as one long string, which makes it harder to pick out a random song.  Try using `readlines()` instead, which returns each line in the file in a list, making it much easier to use `random.choice()`.

And as others have said, using a space to separate the artist and song title makes it much harder to tell where the artist name ends and the song title begins, because the artist and song title can also contain spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this to get a random line:

```
import random

with open("file.txt","r") as f:
    list_of_lines = f.readlines()
    list_of_indexes = list(range(len(list_of_lines)))

    rand_index = random.choice(list_of_indexes)
    random_line = list_of_lines[rand_index]
```

When you get the random line use regular expressions to get the desired elements. This is a useful site to test your regular expression:
https://regex101.com/